# get near paragraph with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this layout:

```
.w3-container.w3-card.w3-black.w3-round.w3-margin
 br
 img.w3-left.w3-circle.w3-margin-right(style="width:60px" src="/w3images/avatar6.png" alt="Avatar")
 span.w3-right.w3-opacity 32 min
 p= p.title 
 if p.picture
  img.w3-margin-bottom(src="images/"+p.picture style="width:100%")
 p= p.content
 if p.votes
  p.w3-input.w3-margin-bottom= p.votes.length    
   i.far.fa-thumbs-up(style='font-size:24px; padding: 5px;') 
 button.w3-button.w3-margin-bottom(type="button" id="test" onclick="voteFunc('"+username+"', '"+p._id+"')")
```

When i click in my button im trying to retrieve the text that its in this paragrapgh `p.w3-input.w3-margin-bottom= p.votes.length`

Im trying something like this `alert($(this).closest('#test').prev('p').text());` but it returns me an empty alert

Comment: Did you use the console to look at the actual HTML? It would be good to add the plain HTML to your question, not just the pug syntax.

Comment: jQuery operates on HTML. Please show that instead of your template markup.

Comment: @Hugo you should use this to convert your pug to html easily:   https://pughtml.com/ or just copy and paste the source from your browser.